# Raycast mouse clicks from Threejs model to the Fabricjs canvas used for the texture

Tags: javascript, three.js, fabricjs, raycasting

I'm creating a 3D product configurator.

**First**, I load the .gltf model and render it with Threejs.

**Then**, I print a svg to a Fabricjs canvas and use that canvas to make a THREE.CanvasTexture and update the model with this canvas.

**The problem**
I allow people to upload text and images. Those images are added to the Fabric canvas as new objects. While the main svg is locked at the background, these uploaded images can be dragged and resized in the canvas.

Screenshot canvas object
[image]

**Goal**
So my goal is to be able to drag and resize those Fabricjs layers interacting directly from the visible 3D threejs model, not the canvas. Because the canvas is display:hidden

Image on the model
[image]

I'm new to this 3D world and can't find any example or guidence so i don't know where to start. 
I know i will have to use Raycasting, but don' know how to convert the points to the correct 2d canvas point and simulate click and drag actions.

Comment: hi where i can find source to create something like that?

Comment: @naovalluthfi you can start here: https://threejs.org/

Comment: well actually i've created the same as u but, have u manage to do that raycast?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this example - https://discourse.threejs.org/t/three-js-fabric-js/2111

Or this - https://codepen.io/ricardcreagia/pen/EdEGod

```
        /**
         * Fabricjs
         * @type {fabric}
         */

        var canvas = new fabric.Canvas( "canvas" );
        canvas.backgroundColor = "#FFBE9F";

        var rectangle = new fabric.Rect( {
            top: 100,
            left: 100,
            fill: '#FF6E27',
            width: 100,
            height: 100,
            transparentCorners: false,
            centeredScaling: true,
            borderColor: 'black',
            cornerColor: 'black',
            corcerStrokeColor: 'black'
        } );

        canvas.add( rectangle );


        /**
         * Threejs
         */

        var containerHeight = "512";
        var containerWidth = "512";
        var camera, renderer, container, scene, texture, material, geometry,cube;

        var raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();
        var mouse = new THREE.Vector2();
        var onClickPosition = new THREE.Vector2();

        init();
        animate();


        /**
         * Configurator init function
         */

        function init() {

            /**
             * Camera
             */

            camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 30, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.01, 100 );
            camera.position.set( 0, 0, 3.5 );


            /**
             * Renderer
             */

            container = document.getElementById( "renderer" );
            renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { antialias: true } );
            renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
            renderer.setSize( containerWidth, containerHeight );
            camera.aspect = container.clientWidth / container.clientHeight;
            camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
            container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );


            /**
             * Scene
             */

            scene = new THREE.Scene();
            scene.background = new THREE.Color( 0x000000 );


            /**
             * Texture and material
             */

            texture = new THREE.Texture( document.getElementById( "canvas" ) );
            texture.anisotropy = renderer.capabilities.getMaxAnisotropy();

            material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: texture } );


            /**
             * Model
             */

             geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 1, 1, 1 );
             cube = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
             scene.add( cube );
        }


        /**
         * Configurator frame render function
         */

        function animate() {
            requestAnimationFrame( animate );

            cube.rotation.x += 0.004;
            cube.rotation.y += 0.001;
            texture.needsUpdate = true;

            renderer.render( scene, camera );
        }


        /**
         * Listeners
         */

        container.addEventListener( "mousedown", onMouseClick, false );


        /**
         * Other methods
         */

        function onMouseClick( evt ) {
            evt.preventDefault();

            var array = getMousePosition( container, evt.clientX, evt.clientY );
            onClickPosition.fromArray( array );

            var intersects = getIntersects( onClickPosition, scene.children );

            if ( intersects.length > 0 && intersects[ 0 ].uv ) {
                var uv = intersects[ 0 ].uv;
                intersects[ 0 ].object.material.map.transformUv( uv );

                var circle = new fabric.Circle({
                    radius: 3,
                    left: getRealPosition( "x", uv.x ),
                    top: getRealPosition( "y", uv.y ),
                    fill: 'red'
                });
                canvas.add( circle );
            }
        }

        function getRealPosition( axis, value ) {
            let CORRECTION_VALUE = axis === "x"
                                    ? 4.5
                                    : 5.5;

            return Math.round( value * 512 ) - CORRECTION_VALUE;
        }

        var getMousePosition = function ( dom, x, y ) {
            var rect = dom.getBoundingClientRect();
            return [ ( x - rect.left ) / rect.width, ( y - rect.top ) / rect.height ];
        };

        var getIntersects = function ( point, objects ) {
            mouse.set( ( point.x * 2 ) - 1, - ( point.y * 2 ) + 1 );
            raycaster.setFromCamera( mouse, camera );
            return raycaster.intersectObjects( objects );
        };
```

I hope this helps someone.

Comment: but can we click on the rectangle and move it around directly from the 3d model?

Comment: I filed a related question in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76069169/how-to-click-on-a-threejs-3dcanvas-to-select-and-modify-a-fabricjs-object)