# How to click on a threejs 3dcanvas to select and modify a fabricjs object

Tags: three.js, fabricjs

I have a threejs scene with a TextureCanvas object.
This TextureCanvas has a FabricJs canvas which contains a rectangle object.
I want to click the object and modify it (e.g. scale,move,modify it) (similar to interacting with it in FabricJs canvas without threejs).

I found ([this](https://jsfiddle.net/prisoner849/rr1bsfsj/show/) and [this](https://codepen.io/ricardcreagia/pen/EdEGod)) with 3dcanvas and 2dcanvas side by side. The user can modify the object in a 2dcanvas.
In [the second example](https://codepen.io/ricardcreagia/pen/EdEGod) the user can click the 3dcanvas which is managed by THREE.WebGLRenderer.
This adds a fabricjs.Circle object which shows up also in the 2dcanvas.
In the 2dcanvas it can be modified (scaled) by dragging the circle corner.

In my case I don't have a view of the 2dcanvas.
I created [another example](https://codepen.io/avnerm/pen/YzJpwLQ?editors=1010), where if I click on the square in the 3dcanvas, it is selected (the corners are shown) and the square is scaled. (the 2dcanvas is still shown, but only for reference).
This demonstrates that I can interact with the fabricjs object via the 3dcanvas.

Next, I want to move, or modify the object as if I clicked in the 2dcanvas.
I have the 2dcanvas coordinates of the mouse.
Is there a function to trigger selection of the closest corner point, and drag action, as if I clicked in the 2dcanvas and dragged?

Thanks,
Avi

```
function onMouseClick( evt ) {
  console.log('BEG renderer onMouseClick');
  evt.preventDefault();

  var array = getMousePosition( container, evt.clientX, evt.clientY );
  onClickPosition.fromArray( array );

  var intersects = getIntersects( onClickPosition, scene.children );

  if ( intersects.length > 0 && intersects[ 0 ].uv ) {
    var uv = intersects[ 0 ].uv;
    intersects[ 0 ].object.material.map.transformUv( uv );

    var x2 = getRealPosition( "x", uv.x );
    var y2 = getRealPosition( "x", uv.y );
    const pointer = {x: x2, y: y2}
    const target = canvas._searchPossibleTargets(canvas.getObjects(), pointer)
    let foundFabricjsObject = false;
    counter +=1;
    console.log('counter: ', counter);
    if (target) {
      console.log('Clicked on a fabricjs object');
      foundFabricjsObject = true;
      target.set('fill', 'red');
      if(counter%2 == 0) {
        console.log('scale the selected fabricjs object by 0.5');
        target.scale(0.5);
      }
      else {
        console.log('scale the selected fabricjs object by 2');
        target.scale(2.0);
      }
        
      canvas.setActiveObject(target).requestRenderAll()
    } else {
      console.log('Clicked NOT on a fabricjs object');
      canvas.discardActiveObject().requestRenderAll()
    }
    
    if(!foundFabricjsObject) {
      var circle = new fabric.Circle({
        radius: 3,
        left: getRealPosition( "x", uv.x ),
        top: getRealPosition( "y", uv.y ),
        fill: 'red'
      });
  
      canvas.add( circle );
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please read [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic): *"Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error **and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.**"*

Comment: Also read [Feedback requested: Runnable code snippets in questions and answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269753/feedback-requested-runnable-code-snippets-in-questions-and-answers)

Comment: I added the example source code and a link to the example that I'm running. I hope this qualifies the question better.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found a solution. See [in here](https://discourse.threejs.org/t/how-to-click-on-a-threejs-3dcanvas-to-select-and-modify-a-fabricjs-object/50719/2)